# select group by column optionally in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to calculate employee salaries.

I have a table and two views which holds data i need to perform a query, here are the tables

```
Employees_View
--------
ID    Name    PayRate    PayUnit    Commission
1    James    10         C          0
2    Mike     10000      S          0
3    Jude     20000      SC         5
4    Clara    8          C          0
```

When PayUnit is C (Commission) then PayRate is in Percent, this is percent of the total sale by this employee, whereas the Commission field is commission percent on total sales and its only for SC employees

### Jobs

```
ID    Created
1     2016-01-21 10:56:05
2     2016-01-21 10:56:05
3     2016-01-21 10:56:05
4     2016-01-21 10:56:05
5     2016-01-21 12:11:59
6     2016-01-25 08:03:07
7     2015-11-01 22:55:22
```

### Jobs_Item_View

```
Job_ID    Amount    Emp_ID
1        135         4
1        500         2
3        1500        2
3        250         4
4        1000        2
5        500         4
6        500         4
7        500         1
```

### PayUnits

```
Code    Name
S       Salary   
C       Commission
SC      Salary plus Commission
```

Here is what i tried

```
SELECT 
    ev.PayRate, 
    ev.name AS Employee, 
    CASE ev.PayUnitCode WHEN 'C' THEN 
        SUM(jiv.Amount) - (SUM(jiv.Amount) * (ev.PayRate / 100))  
    WHEN 'SC' THEN 
        ev.payrate + SUM(jiv.Amount) - (SUM(jiv.Amount) * (ev.Commission / 100))
    ELSE ev.payrate 
    END AS pay,
    LEFT(DATENAME(month, j.Created), 3) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(j.Created) AS NVARCHAR) AS Month, 
    jiv.Emp_ID, 
    pu.Name AS PayUnit, 
     ev.Code, ev.Commission
FROM 
    dbo.Employees_View AS ev LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Job_Items_View AS jiv  ON jiv.Emp_ID = ev.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Jobs AS j ON j.ID = jiv.Job_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.PayUnits AS pu ON pu.Code = ev.PayUnitCode

GROUP BY jiv.Emp_ID, 
        pu.Name, 
        ev.PayUnitCode,
        ev.PayRate, ev.name, 
        LEFT(DATENAME(month, j.Created), 3) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(j.Created) AS NVARCHAR), 
        ev.Code, ev.Commission
```

This is what i got

### Result

```
PayRate Employee pay   Month    Emp_ID  PayUnit                 Commission
20000   Jude    NULL   NULL     NULL    Salary plus Commission  5.00
10      James   900    Nov-2015 1       Commission              0.00
8       Clara   2760   Jan-2016 4       Commission              0.00
10000   Mike    10000  Jan-2016 2       Salary                  0.00
```

Expected Output

### Result

```
PayRate Employee pay     Month  Emp_ID  PayUnit                 Commission
20000   Jude    20241.75 Jan-2016   3       Salary plus Commission  5.00
10      James   900      Nov-2015   1       Commission              0.00
8       Clara   2760     Jan-2016   4       Commission              0.00
10000   Mike    10000    Jan-2016   2       Salary                  0.00
```

the Pay for the SC employee isn't correct. it is suppose to be Salary (20000) plus 5% or total sales (4835) which is 241.75 - 20,241.75

Comment: It would be nice to have the table creation and data inserts in a script in there, make it easy on those that want to help you  ([How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/spaghettidba/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/))

Comment: Your `Jobs_Item_View` table was defined as having two columns `Job_ID` and `Amount`, but you refer to a column called `Emp_ID` in the query.  In any case, my guess is that you need to change your join strategy, which might be whence the `NULL` values are.

Comment: I don't see from the sample data how Employee ID is related/linked to an Amount. Something is missing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I made the necessary correction

Comment: The `Employees_View.ID` doesn't match the `Emp_ID` in your results. For example, Clara is `4` in the view, but `2` in the results!

Comment: @davmos It was a typo error, I have corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the nulls is that one of the employees did not contribute to any jobs, so `SUM(jiv.Amount)` will always be `null` for them and any calculations involving that expression will also result in `null`. You can fix by doing `ISNULL(SUM(jiv.Amount), 0)`. Similarly for the dates, they are also driven by the jobs data, but if an employee wasn't involved in any jobs they will be `null` also. `ISNULL()` could be used for these as well.

I've broken the problem down by using [Common Table Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
DECLARE @startDateTime DATETIME = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
DECLARE @endDateTime DATETIME = '2016-01-31 23:59:59'

;WITH sales AS
(
  SELECT 
    ev.ID,
    ISNULL(SUM(jiv.Amount), 0) AS TotalSales,
    MONTH(j.Created) AS [Month],
    YEAR(j.Created) AS [Year]
  FROM Employees_View AS ev
  LEFT JOIN Job_Items_View AS jiv ON jiv.Emp_ID = ev.ID
  LEFT JOIN Jobs AS j ON j.ID = jiv.Job_ID
  WHERE j.Created BETWEEN @startDateTime AND @endDateTime
  GROUP BY 
    ev.ID,
    MONTH(j.Created),
    YEAR(j.Created)
),
commissions AS
(
  SELECT
    s.ID,
    CASE ev.PayUnitCode 
      WHEN 'C' THEN s.TotalSales * (ev.PayRate / 100)   
      WHEN 'SC' THEN (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Job_Items_View) * (ev.Commission / 100)
      ELSE 0
    END AS TotalCommission
  FROM sales AS s
  JOIN Employees_View AS ev ON ev.ID = s.ID
),
salaries AS
(
  SELECT 
    ID, 
    CASE PayUnitCode 
      WHEN 'C' THEN 0 
      ELSE PayRate 
    END AS Salary 
  FROM Employees_View 
),
totals AS
(
  SELECT 
    salaries.ID,
    ISNULL(sales.Month, MONTH(@startDateTime)) AS [Month],
    ISNULL(sales.Year, YEAR(@startDateTime)) AS [Year],
    ISNULL(sales.TotalSales, 0) AS TotalSales,
    salaries.Salary,
    ISNULL(commissions.TotalCommission, 0) AS TotalCommission
  FROM salaries
  LEFT JOIN sales ON salaries.ID = sales.ID
  LEFT JOIN commissions ON commissions.ID = sales.ID
)
SELECT 
  ev.PayRate,
  ev.Name,
  t.Salary + t.TotalCommission AS Pay,
  LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH , t.[Month], -1)), 3) 
    + '-' + CAST(t.[Year] AS VARCHAR) AS [Month],
  ev.ID AS Emp_ID,
  pu.Name AS PayUnit,
  ev.Commission
FROM totals AS t
JOIN Employees_View AS ev ON ev.ID = t.ID
JOIN PayUnits AS pu ON pu.Code = ev.PayUnitCode
```

[**Click here to see it in action and have a play on SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97861/22).

Comment: I corrected the error, it was a typo. Besides the Pay for the SC employee isn't correct. it is suppose to be Salary (20000) plus 5% or total sales (4835) which is 241.75 - 20,241.75

Comment: OK, updated answer & fiddle link. But I make the total sales 4885, not 4835.

Comment: can i filter the results between two dates?

Comment: Refactored & added example date filter for you

Comment: the refactored version does not calculate correctly for the `SC`, I have been trying different edits but not successful yet

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What are you getting/expecting? I've updated the fiddle link, as SQL Fiddle was down when I tried the other day.

Comment: the `SC` pay is suppose to be `20244.25`, but its `2000` instead.

Comment: Goto the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97861/22 ... the `Pay` column shows `20244.25` for the `SC` employee.

Comment: for example the pay for `John` with `emp_id = 1` cannot be zero

Comment: He's on commission-only and the date filter didn't include his only job. I've updated the date filter in the fiddle to include all jobs: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97861/23

Comment: in order to reveal the error, look at the `Job_Items_View` values, i replaced all **emp_id** `3` to `4`. This is because emp_id 3 earns commission based on the valuse of the commission field in the employees table and this is the percentage of total sales, while emp_id `3` commission is based on the payrate field check  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4be2/1  . You can see that emp_id 4 gets only salary istead of salary plus 5% of total sales

Comment: I found that the sales CTE is not selecting the employee with `SC` is joining `job_items_view` to `employee_views` on the condition that the employee id exists in the `job_items_view`